# c# listbox - first selected item is played

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my problem: I have a TextBox, button, and a ListBox. The functions works right but whenever I search flash videos, the moment I click the search button, the first video on the list is played. I don't want it to be played on that time - I want to choose from the list without playing the first highlighted item on the ListBox.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path = "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Video\\FLASH";
    listBox1.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + txtbox1.Text + "*")
                       .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f))
                       .ToList();
}
```

This is the search button. It will search the text on `textbox1` from the specified path:

```
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = listBox1.SelectedItem as string;
    if (fileName != null)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Video\\FLASH", fileName);
        Process.Start(path);
    }    
}
```

This is the ListBox, the searched items will be here, but there is always one item selected and that item plays whenever the search finished.

Comment: if i understood correctly when you click `button1_Click` it is playing video right?

Comment: yes it is , but what i want it to do is to first show all the results, without playing anything ..  and im the one who will click it and play it ..

Comment: I believe you can use ClearSelected to clear the selected items in the listbox.

Comment: how can i use that clear selected ? would you mind putting it on my code please?

Comment: Do you have a `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler? This one would be triggered when setting the listbox's data source.

Comment: i dont hace that listbox1_selectedindexChanged .. where should i put it ?

Comment: in your form select listbox and see the properties window in that window open event tab and then double click on SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: No such problem is indicated by the posted code. It definitely sounds like you have a `SelectedIndexChanged` or similar event handler on the `ListBox`. In particular, it sounds like you have `listBox1_DoubleClick` handling one of those events rather than the `DoubleClick` event. We need more information to give a more definitive answer.

Comment: As for your question re: ClearSelected, you would add it to the end of your button click event [i.e., listbox1.ClearSelected()]. Your fileName variable would be null at this point.

Comment: it clears the selected, but before it clear, it open the first item on the list ..

Comment: i was able to solve this problem on my own .. thanks btw. :)

Answer (score 1):

Fill the list, then add the selectedindexchanged event handler. (Make sure that the event isn't added for you by the designer).

So, 
listBox1.DataSource = ...

listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += 
 new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);